# dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 0

Tags: apt, dpkg

Been trying to install git-core package for almost more than half a day now. Every time I do, I get this error:

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 0:
newline in field name `../../../../../share/pyshared/UpdateManager/Core/__init__.py'
```

I've also tried running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing`. Even tried rebooting and cleaning the apt-get cache, still doesnt work.

Comment: Finally, a solution!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The problem is that your `/var/lib/dpkg/available` file is damaged.

This is not necessarily related to the git or git-core packages. Try to install any other package and they will fail too.

To fix this you have to delete/clear the file using the command:

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
```

then rebuild the file using the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you should be able to install git and git-core.

Answer (score 1):

From the below error,it was clearly shown that your `/var/lib/dpkg/available` file was corrupted.

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 0:
newline in field name `../../../../../share/pyshared/UpdateManager/Core/__init__.py'
```

Solution for the above problem is to replace the current `/var/lib/dpkg/available` file with another `/var/lib/dpkg/available-old` backup file.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
```

Now try,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```