# Unable to install software or update ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55099/dpkg-error-parsing-file-var-lib-dpkg-available-near-line-0)

I receive the following error and update or installs fail.

```
InstallArchives() failed: dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 0:
 field name `../../../../../share/pyshared/ubuntutweak/policykit/dbusproxy.py' must be followed by colon
```