# Can't install ANY applications

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dpkg: error: parsing file ‘/var/lib/dpkg/available’ near line 0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55099/dpkg-error-parsing-file-var-lib-dpkg-available-near-line-0)

Every application install attmept end in failure with this showing in the details:

installArchives() failed: dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 0:
 newline in field name `ipts'

Existing apps work

Comment: post the entire error message

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands on the terminal

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail

sudo apt-get update
```

think this will resolve the issue.