# Why can't I update my repository updates in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, updates, java

I tried to install updates via the update manager, so then I used terminal and got

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 0:
field name `../../../../java-7-openjdk-common/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar' must be followed by colon
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

so if anyone could help me i would appreciate that thank you

Comment: what was the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: great answer found here http://askubuntu.com/questions/55099/dpkg-error-parsing-file-var-lib-dpkg-available-near-line-0?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

From the below error,it was clearly shown that your `/var/lib/dpkg/available` file was corrupted.

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 0:
field name `../../../../java-7-openjdk-common/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar' must be followed by colon
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Solution for the above problem is to replace the current `/var/lib/dpkg/available` file with another `/var/lib/dpkg/available-old` backup file.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
```

Now try,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```