# Message 'E:dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.'

Tags: 14.04, dpkg

Whenever I am trying to get the update I am getting the error at the last line:

```
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en_IN
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

And then according to the prompted error when I run:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0009' near line 0:
 newline in field name `#padding'
```

What now? Can I get out of the error?

I tried this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55099/dpkg-error-parsing-file-var-lib-dpkg-available-near-line-0).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You referred a wrong link. Try the below commands on terminal to remove all the files inside `/var/lib/dpkg/updates` directory ,

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates
sudo rm *
```

And then run the below command to get newer ones,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: it works fine for me .

Comment: This worked for me on Raspbmc/Raspbian as well. However, I'm curious - is this a safe solution?

Comment: this worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Comment: Still works in 2016 for ubuntu-15.04(-based Zorin OS 10)!

Comment: THANK YOU so much for this solution.  I was searching forever to find a way to clear the error when I intentionally interrupted the dpkg installation of a problematic .deb file.  I truly appreciate your advice!

Comment: it works fine for me

Answer (score 5):

It works for me! I was trying to install the wireless driver when this error came. Had to delete the files and also the lock files.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates
sudo rm *
sudo apt-get update
```

and then you can run your `apt-get install` to whatever package you want to install

Comment: Not necessarily a good idea without extra precautions.

Comment: This worked for me when the previous answer didn't, although I'm not sure it wasn't without side effects...