# Terminal no longer opens

Tags: dpkg, gnome-terminal

(First off this is my first linux download to a virtual machine)

Basically I followed a step by step YouTube guide
I installed everything until the updates
There were originally 1300 updates
Now there are 222 updates left
Whenever I try to update them I get the 
"you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' " dialog
Seems simple enough. I had to do that twice before. However, whenever I go to terminal and click on it it just loads on the upper right and then it never opens. 
Is there a workaround to this? OR solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get to the terminal at all. You can always use 1 of the 6 tty sessions. In all Linux distributions, ctrl+alt+F1 will open the first tty session. You can login from there an use it just like the gnome terminal. Then, take a look at the link below.

[similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483611/message-edpkg-was-interrupted-you-must-manually-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a)

Follow the steps in the answer. It looks like the same problem you are having.