# Getting error while running sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, google-chrome, dpkg

Whenever I am running `$ sudo apt-get update`, I am getting the following error.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martin-frost/thoughtbot-rcm/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                             
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                     
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]                                                                    
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-lxc/lxd-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                   
Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                             
Ign:8 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily InRelease                                                                                           
Hit:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                                                          
Get:11 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily Release [6,596 B]                                                                                  
Hit:12 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                                          
Ign:9 http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./ InRelease                                                                                           
Hit:14 http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./ Release                                                               
Ign:16 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb stable InRelease
Ign:17 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:18 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb stable Release
Hit:19 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:22 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial InRelease
Fetched 101 kB in 5s (17.0 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

chrome being the rogue repo here. I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483611/message-edpkg-was-interrupted-you-must-manually-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a)  question and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741410/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages-as-repository-x) similar to the problem that I was facing

**What I have tried**

As suggested in one of the answers, I tried running

```
$ cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates && sudo rm * 
$ sudo apt-get update
```

As well as checking the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

My architechture

```
$ uname -a
Linux Acer 4.4.0-24-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 19:27:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 51.0.2704.106
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. Here's how I fixed it:

1. First, I executed this shell command in order to add **[arch=amd64]** back into the *Chrome Remote Desktop* repository file:

   ```
   sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/chrome-remote-desktop.list"
   ```
2. Then I did the same to the *Chrome Remote Desktop* cron file:

   ```
   sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/cron.daily/chrome-remote-desktop"
   ```
3. After doing that, I executed APT again, just to make sure everything was back to normal as it should be:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get check
   ```

Comment: I had suggested changing file permission to 444 (making it read-only for everyone), but it didn't work because CRD is executed during boot up (cron file read by the init script), and under such circumstance the file is fully accessible by the system, no matter if it's read-only. Hence, the only option left is to change the *cron* configuration file in order to force it to look for the "amd64" repository, only.

Comment: I sent a bug report to Google and they fixed the problem. Hence, nowadays all the user has to do is to upgrade _Chrome Remote Desktop_ by running this shell supercommand: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get check && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y`

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually remove the google sources from the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` after which I uninstalled google chrome

```
$ sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser
```

Downloaded google chrome again from their website and everything was back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:
1.Restart the comptuer and try again.
2. Uninstall chrome, run the updates, reinstall chrome. To be sure i'd do it in this fashion:

```
 sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt-get autoremove
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

If you want to keep your settings you can just log in to your google account on the browser.