# dpkg always failing, complaining about missing package name

Tags: 14.04, live-usb, dpkg

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 from a liveUSB due to a problem with my HDD. Today I was trying to install Steam, but the installation failed every time. Some testing later, I noticed every installation of anything at all fails now, because of `dpkg` throwing the following error:

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 31:
 missing package name
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I also can't seem to manage to uninstall and reinstall `dpkg`, but that may just be my poor Linux skillz.

Any ideas why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: don't uninstall dpkg or you'll be left without a paddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages file is corrupted. You can fix them with the steps below as discussed in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55099/dpkg-error-parsing-file-var-lib-dpkg-available-near-line-0)

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
```

and the rebuild using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: heheh it's fine (y) Cheers!

Comment: Glad it did :D Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For me, i simply just replace the current corrupted available file with the old one like this

```
 #rename the corrupted file to available.crpt
 sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/available /var/lib/dpkg/available.crpt
 #now recreate the available.old file to the current required one.
 sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available.old /var/lib/dpkg/available 
 #update the package list 
 sudo apt-get update
```

And that is how i solved mine. chap chap